# Resizing frames in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am creating a WPF application where I have 4 frames like the next image:

(I couldn't post an image because I need 10 reputation =/ )

Each frame would load a page.xaml, so what I want to do is the next:

When I click on a frame I would like to resize the frame to the size of the window and when I click again resize backwards to the original size.

Well I'll try to show the design of my window, this would be the main window with 4 frames:

|  F1  |   |  F2  |

|  F3  |   |  F4  |

And when I click one frame it resizes:

|-----F1-----|

I am kinda new using WPF so I am not sure how can I accomplish this effect, maybe using an event or just changing the size and position of the frame.

Regards,

Juan Alberto

Comment: What is in the frames? Do you have an image or WPF controls or something else? When it is small are all the controls tiny? One way of shrinking a UI element uniformly is using a ScaleTransform. Show me a little code and I can help more.

Comment: What are your frames in?  Are they in some sort of panel?  That will control the way they are presented.

Answer (score 0):

If your not following MVVM and your just doing all your actions, then you can simply Hide other 3 frames when you click on F1 and set it's size to layout size, again toggle back when click on it once again